# How to output the result file of ansys to webgl?

Tags: webgl, ansys, vtk.js

I have calculated the results in ansys apdl or workbench. Is there any way to export them as gltf? I hope these results can be browsed in threejs.I have tried the method of exporting vtk with ansys, but it has not been able to run successfully.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to Ansys Ensigth, the export from to GLTF 2.0 seems possible but I haven't tested it. Here is an overview of result export [options](https://www.padtinc.com/2021/01/06/ansys-mechanical-outputting-results-5-3d-result-object/).

Comment: Hi, thank you, according to your method and solved the problem.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.